# Why does Traveler 001 not suffer from temporal aphasia?

Tags: travelers

Why does Traveler 001 (Vincent Ingram) not suffer from temporal aphasia the way Trevor (0115) does? After all he switched hosts probably as many times, going by the few hints we get about it from Trevor.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do more with physical age of the mind. Traveler 001 probably wasn't very old in the future when he traveled back in comparison to Trevor who was very old. Additionally, it isn't a guarantee for anyone. There has only been 1 other case thus who knows what the actual cause of the disease is.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking the time to answer. Do you have any sources? Any specific statements of any of the characters or even something non-canonical that backs this up? Because when I followed that latest season I did not get this out of anything stated by the characters. But then, I may have simply missed it.

Comment: Re-watch it. I don't have the quotes on hand, but 0115 has had multiple hosts and lived for hundreds of years.

While someone else might have had multiple hosts, their core consciousness isn't as old as 0115.

It seems to come from the age of the consciousness and not related to how many hosts they've had.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s also because 0115 had multiple hosts whereas there hasn’t been indication that 001 inhabited multiple host bodies. Like trevor explained the only other person who experienced this was the only other person who inhabited multiple host bodies (his wife) so I’m sure that’s why.

Comment: Yes he did, in season 3. Which is the reason why I asked this question in the first place. I am fairly certain that all that talk by Trevor was part of the mechanism allowing the viewer to understand the "rules of the game", so to speak.