# How many times did Trevor switch hosts?

Tags: travelers

This question is related to [my previous question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/201721/21673).

Crisp and simple: how many times did Trevor (0115) switch hosts? This is relevant, because it relates directly to the plot device of his condition called *temporal aphasia*.

Comment: I'm not sure a definitive answer was given, though it did seem that more transfers increased the risk, though the experimental sample size is too small to say for sure, since he is only the second case.